# Call method on deleting notification

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification

I know that it's possible to call activity on deleting notification by user with `setDeleteIntent`. But I don't want to open a new activity when user deletes (swipes, dismisses) notification, I want to call a method in background, how I should to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** Use [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) for that purpose. Declare it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` and pass `PendingIntent` that will send broadcast to it. So you can use this call to run your function.

**Option 2** Use [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) or [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for that purpose. Again, just declare your service in `AndroidManifest.xml`, and set up `PendingIntent` accordingly. Then handle call inside service implementation in order to call your method.

Comment: Third option would be using Activity without UI

Comment: Probably, however I avoided this option because question says 'But I don't want to open a new activity when user deletes (swipes, dismisses) notification' :)

Comment: Yes was thinking about it at first too, but he probably just didint want any window to show up

Comment: @VygintasB no, really, I don't want any activities, because if user dismisses notification it means that my app mustn't annoy him.